# Split and allocate values according a distribution

Tags: r

Say I have a vector of `oldPopulation` counts in 2018 for 200 counties in a state and a `newPopulation` projection for 2025 of say, `5000`.

I'd like to split the 5000 new people into 200 county groups such that the proportion of projected population in each group is comparable to the existing county population.

Say that we have an existing county population distribution like so:

```
oldPopulation <- abs(rnorm(200, mean = 100, sd = 50))
```

The goal is to add the correctly proportional amount of `newPopulation` to each `oldPopulation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll just want some good, old-fashioned arithmetic for this one:

```
oldPopulation <- abs(rnorm(200, mean = 100, sd = 50))

proportion <- oldPopulation/sum(oldPopulation)

newPopulation <- proportion*(sum(oldPopulation) + 5000)
```

Comment: You could even skip the second line and use `prop.table(oldPopulation)*5000 + oldPopulation`